# C# Using TextBox over MaskedTextBox for IP input. Masking Issues

Tags: c#

A couple of articles I read on StackOverflow have indicated to use `TextBox` over `MaskedTextBox` as such I have used the `TextBox` to capture the IP from my users.

I found a good regex pattern from StackOverflow to validate whether the IP is valid

`string pattern = @"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$";`

It generates a true bool on being valid. However with using a `TextBox` I am left wondering how do I add masking to the `TextBox` so that not only the default text is 0.0.0.0 but when typing an IP into the box it keeps the period marks in place and as such the user does not need to enter them so that their only input is the numbers.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: it is actually tricky, you need to write quite a few lines!

Comment: @AppDeveloper Do you know of any references anywhere that touch on it. Its not what I wanted to hear but I would at least like to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had to do something similar to take IPv4 as input from user.

I have used this free control.

[IP Address Control](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddresscontrollib/)

An article related to that control : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9352/A-C-IP-Address-Control

---

Seems to be a light-weight control, haven't tested it, found on Google!
http://sanity-free.org/127/an_ipaddress_control_the_win32_sysipaddress32_control_in_csharp.html

Comment: This looks somewhat promising. I agree with it's author why MS never included a default control seems madness!

Comment: @RyanWalkowski - not everyone needs to work with IPv4 input, its not that common!

Comment: I can see your point, I guess i am been selfish in my own demands really!

Comment: well a quick google search gave one more promising result : http://sanity-free.org/127/an_ipaddress_control_the_win32_sysipaddress32_control_in_csharp.html

Comment: I use Google so much, Sometimes I fear I am just not searching the correct search terms to find the results I seek. But thanks its certainly a starting point I'll look into!

Comment: @RyanWalkowski - thnx for askin this question, it actually helped me understand something :)!

Answer (score 0):

I was seeking something very similar.  I found that in using a simpler regex in conjunction with IPAddress.TryParse I could use the text changed and validating event handlers on the text box to ensure a valid IP4 was entered.  In the following example the textbox name was tbIPInput.  Some Font decorating to help identify what is happening during the execution.  The validating part prevents a person from exiting the textbox until a valid IP is entered.

```
private void tbIPInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regPattern = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+");
        if (regPattern.IsMatch(tbIPInput.Text) && IPAddress.TryParse(tbIPInput.Text, out IPAddress address))
        {
            //Valid IP is detected
            tbIPInput.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            tbIPInput.Font = new Font(tbIPInput.Font, FontStyle.Regular);

        }
        else
        {
            //Invalid IP entered so far
            tbIPInput.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            tbIPInput.Font = new Font(tbIPInput.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        }

    }

    private void tbIPInput_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regPattern = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+");
        if (regPattern.IsMatch(tbIPInput.Text) && IPAddress.TryParse(tbIPInput.Text, out IPAddress address))
        {
            //Valid IP is detected
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Invalid IP entered so far do not allow focus to change
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```